# OpenAPI 3.0 Nested Array Clarification

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-editor

A bit new to OpenAPI and had a question revolving around nested arrays.The documentation for OpenAPI 3.0 shows that one can create the schema for a nested array as such:

```
# [ [1, 2], [3, 4] ]
type: array
items:
  type: array
  items:
    type: integer
```

I've tried using the Swagger Editor to create my own get request using a nested array which can be see here...

```
/astar/findLocalMaxiams:
    get:
      tags:
      - A Star Search
      summary: Finds Local Maximas by Elevation
      description: Returns an array of local maximas throughout the terrain using
        its corresponding elevations
      operationId: find_maximas
      parameters:
      - name: elevationData
        in: query
        description: Elevation data
        required: true
        style: form
        explode: true
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            type: array
            items:
              type: number
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Point'
                x-content-type: application/json
            application/xml:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Point'
        "400":
          description: Invalid elevation data format
```

But I keep getting an error thrown that a value is not of type array thus failing to validating the type in the schema.
[Swagger UI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CMvV.png)
[Python Error]

```
>>> arr = [[5, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [8, 8, 3]]
>>> params = {'elevationData': arr}
>>> requests.get('http://localhost:5000/astar/findLocalMaxiams', params=params).content
b'{\n  "detail": "\'5\' is not of type \'array\'\\n\\nFailed validating \'type\' in schema[\'items\']:\\n    {\'items\': {\'type\': \'number\'}, \'type\': \'array\'}\\n\\nOn instance[0]:\\n    \'5\'",\n  "status": 400,\n  "title": "Bad Request",\n  "type": "about:blank"\n}\n'
```

I've tried changing the schema to a single array which does work but it defeats the purpose since the structure of the 2-D array is needed to compute extremes base on neighboring elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a complex object that can't easily be expressed in a standard URI.  Try using content instead of schema

```yaml
paths:
  /astar/findLocalMaxiams:
    get:
      tags:
        - A Star Search
      summary: Finds Local Maximas by Elevation
      description: Returns an array of local maximas throughout the terrain using
        its corresponding elevations
      operationId: find_maximas
      parameters:
        - name: elevationData
          in: query
          description: Elevation data
          required: true
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    type: number
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Point'
                x-content-type: application/json
            application/xml:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Point'
        "400":
          description: Invalid elevation data format
```

Comment: Thanks! So I found the documentation regarding content vs schema since you brought it up and I did try wrap the schema with the content and json tags as you've shown but all that does is cause an exception to raise within the connexion library. I'm beginning to wonder if it would be easier to use a post request instead of get in this situation but I wasn't sure if its okay to return content using a post request.